# Convert DataTable to Dictionary with enum as column C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, datatable

There is one Enum viz. CarEnum having values
All - 1
BMW - 2
Audi - 3

I am getting this DataTable from database

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", long);
dt.Columns.Add("EnumID", Int16);
```

I want to convert this table into `Dictionary` with `EnumID` as `Enum`

Dictionary format

```
Dictionary<long, CarEnum> _Record = new Dictionary<long, CarEnum>();
```

I have tries below codes but they are not

```
_Record = dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, long, CarEnum>(row => row.Field<long>("ID"), row => (CarEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(CarEnum), row.Field<Int16>("EnumID")));
_Record = dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, long, CarEnum>(row => row.Field<long>("ID"), row => (CarEnum)(int)row.Field<Int16>("EnumID"));
```

both codes are not working and got exception specific cast in not valid.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you want the Enum type? Don't you have a specific enum instead?

Comment: `Enum` is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: I have specific Enum. I want to add Enum type in Dictionary as column on basis of EnumID from datatable.

Comment: Then use this specific enum not the Enum type.

Comment: I have used specific Enum but not working. Let me rewrite code again so that you will not get confused.

Comment: @MaheshWaghmare I have tried your second approach and it works fine for me. Please add the Target Enum type definition to the question to check if it's causing any problem. Note that the proper way to add a column to DataTable object is dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(long)).

Comment: Try to use short instead of Int16

Comment: Got the issue. Issue was with Data Type. Thanks All for helping.

Comment: @MaheshWaghmare I'm not sure what's the problem with Data Type. Please add the same to be helpful in case of if someone come across the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you can cast only specific primitive to enum.

Please see [this link to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

Use short instead of Int16 or cast Int16 to short before casting to enum.

Edit:
Maybe you trying to cast a zero value and it is not defined in your enum ?

Comment: The cast is from Int16 to Int32 which will be a valid cast but not the vice-versa

Comment: Any value will get cast to it's integral equivalent as long as it's in the Enum underlying type's range. Hence even though zero is not defined it will be valid as it's in the range. Please check the image in my answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you telling me that

Comment: Just trying to provide the correct info. No offence :)

Comment: Didn't know about 0 thing, thanks! But what about Int32 thing ?

Comment: The conversion is always valid from a smaller integral datatype to a bigger integral datatype in C# but not vice-versa unless the integral literal value of bigger datatype can fit into the smaller datatype. This is to avoid any overflow errors in the runtime. Please refer to this link for more info [short (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your second approach and it works fine for me.

[image]

Comment: @DownVoters It would be better to add the reason to help improving the answer.